# None live search Data using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

Hello I am currently working on a project and have managed to connect a very big size database to a website and use ajax live search to search for data from the database. However I have been looking everywhere to find a none live version of the ajax live search. The current one displays all the data from the database on the webpage which is fine if i have small data in the database but I want the page to only show data when user searches and enters or just when searches. Same functions as what the current ajax live search does just without having to display data on the webpage without user searching first. This is the javascript code from ajax live search:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
```

I am wondering what change i can make to make it so when i visit the page no data is being displayed unless i search using the searchbox ?

Comment: Don't call `load_data();` when document is ready? The function is explicitly called every time the page loads.

Comment: @El_Vanja but if i remove load_data then when i attempt to search no data is being displayed.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Just to be on a safe side and make sure we understand each other, I'm talking about that first line within your script. It instructs the browser to run the function when the page loads. Removing that shouldn't have an effect on the calls of the function that are being made when input is detected in the `#search_text` element.

Comment: Ah yes i understand you now. Sorry about the misunderstanding. So yes that works now. However when i have entered the information and i have deleted the words. the page in the end displays all the data from the database. When i refresh all is gone until i search again and when i cut it out again then it just shows all the data once again.@El_Vanja

Comment: @El_Vanja is there a method i can use so once i have finished searching and the search bar is empty again then instead of displaying all the data from database the script functions same as how when i visit the page first and it shows no data unless something has been entered in the search ?

Comment: Can you modify the last sentence in your question to include this extra specification (not displaying data when search bar is empty) and I'll explain the whole thing in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid loading data before a search is made, you need to remove the function call at the beginning of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data(); // this line needs to be removed
    ...
}
```

When you explicitly call a function, it gets executed. Being wrapped in `$(document).ready()` it's instructing the browser to run the function when the page loads.

If you wish to remove the data once the search box is cleared, you need to modify your event handler like so:

```
if (search != '') {
    load_data(search);
} else {
    // this is where "load_data();" used to be
    $('#result').html('');
}
```

This replaces any content that might have been appended to the displaying element in a previous search.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just finished it off with this and it works perfectly! the ajax live search was good as default but once search was clearned it still showed data which just did not make any sense. Now this way it is perfect. Thank you so much for this! appreciate it. New to Php/Ajax so still learning.